# MongoDB Document Update in Java: coding error or driver bug?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I'm using MongoDB [Java Driver v3.2.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/java/#download-upgrade) and I use the following instruction to add a new String array field into an existing document:

```
myMongoCollection.updateOne(new Document("id", id), Updates.set("arrayField", Arrays.asList(new Document("strField", strValue))));
```

It creates the following exception:

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find
>   a codec for class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.

Am I doing a coding error or is it related to the Driver bug as suggested [here (link)](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2056)?

If it is related to the driver bug, any hint how I can easily get the latest not-yet-released version (3.3) where is has been fixed (ie. how can I easily create a JAR file, knowing that GIT is completely new to me)?

Many thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [mongodb-java-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver) v3.2.2, you could use `Document` instead of `Updates.set` builder. See also [Updating Documents](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/#updating-documents)

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;

myMongoCollection.updateOne(eq("id", id), new Document("$set", new Document ("arrayField", Arrays.asList(new Document("strField", strValue)))));
```

Alternatively, if the fix has gone into the master branch, you could build the jar from git:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver.git
$ cd mongo-java-driver
$ ./gradlew
```

The resulting jar would be in `build/libs` directory.